# CSS: Keep equal distance between strings despite font-size changes

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a lockscreen for my phone. Check [this image](http://www.maggadget.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/wp7lockscreen.jpg) so you get an impression.

In order to keep the date nicely fit across the width of the screen, I decided to dynamically let the font-size change, whenever the string changes in width (e.g. "May" is wider than "Jul"). Because of this, the bigger the font, the closer it gets to the line above. I would like to have a fixed distance. In the case of the image that the top of the "A" in "Aug" keeps equal distance to the bottom of the "y" in "Sunday".

If anyone knows how to do this, I'm happy to hear it.

Here's the Javascript code:

```
for (var i = $("#date").css("font-size").slice(0, -2); $("#date").width() < $("#clock").width()-2; i++)
        $("#date").css("font-size", i.toString() + "px");
```

The complete CSS:

```
body { font-family: Calibri; color: #fff; text-shadow: -1px 0 #585858, 0 1px #585858, 1px 0 #585858, 0 -1px #585858; background-color: #000; position: relative; }
#clock { width: 280px; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin: -.7em 0 0 40px; font-size: 53px; } //e.g. 5:30 AM
#day { font-size: 0.9em; line-height: 35px; } //e.g. Sunday
#date { margin-top: 15px; position: absolute; font-size: 90px; line-height: 55px; } //e.g. 5 Aug
```

The relevant HTML structure:

```
<body>
<div id="clock">
    <div id="day">
    </div>
    <div id="date">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: are lockscreen images generated with CSS?

Comment: I'm using html, javascript and CSS for the lockscreen. This question only relates to CSS, at least I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mess with the `line-height` of the element until the upper boundary of the element is at the top of the font, then margin it down from the element above as needed.

Hopefully my example will do a better job than my explanation:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYecS/3/

Comment: I was thinking of that.. Unfortunately the actual line seems 'shifted' with respect to the letters. For example, when I select the text, the upper edge of the selection might go through the letters.

Comment: Well, yes, but do you really need to be able to select the text if all that matters is that the font appears to maintain the same distance from the above line?

Comment: You're right that the selection might not be related to the problem. However, it's still not working. I think it has something to do with the Javascript because when I turn off the dynamic font changing it seems to work. I've compiled an image so you can see the problem: http://tinyurl.com/cnp6mqu I've also update my post with the related Javasript code if that helps.

Comment: Can you also post all the other styles you have applied to the text?

Comment: Does setting a fixed *height* also achieve the same effect?

Comment: Jcubed, Did that, also added the relevant HTML structure. Wex, Height seems to have no effect if I place it inside #date.

Comment: Your defining `line-height` using px, but you need to define it using no units. When you put a unitless number into line-height, it multiplies the font size by that number to get the line height in px. Use `line-height:0.7`.

Comment: Note: You may need to use a number different from 0.7 depending on the font, just make sure it has no units.

Comment: That was it! Thanks very much, hadn't thought of that. A value of 0.6 was about the sweet spot. Out of curiosity, is this kind of thing also possible for the space on the left of the string? It's not much of a problem because I can just use e.g. left: -3; but it would be nice if it were possible..

Comment: Try `text-indent` using units of `em` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-indent)

Comment: Thanks, it basically results in the same as `left`. It doesn't really affect the the space in the character block like `line-height` does. I wouldn't be surprised if this is impossible to do - I think this space is just 'built in' the character.

Comment: Kind of yeah.. Only I would need to change the spacing on the left side of the letter (instead of the right) and only for the first character.